# JTable Focus Movement Query?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to highlight the focus movement in the `JTable` through this code:

```
    if(e.getKeyCode() == (KeyEvent.VK_TAB)){
                int prevRow;
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
                if(col == 0) {
                System.out.println(row);
                MinMax val = null;
                TableCellRenderer currRend = table.getCellRenderer(row,col);
                val = (MinMax) table.getValueAt(row, col);
                JComponent comp = (JComponent) currRend.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, val, false, false, row,col);
                comp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
                table.requestFocus(true);   
}
```

The scenario is this, when I press TAB for the first time the second row is selected, initially the focus is set on row[0], the border is not painted, when I press the second time the third row is selected highlighting both 2 and 3rd row.

After that whenever tab is pressed, the highlighting of the border becomes relevant to the row selection.

I am facing issue when I am running the application under normal mode and not under de-bugger mode with break points.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: BTW - what is your question?  (And no, adding a ? to the words in the title does not make it a question!)

Comment: @ Andrew: This is what i am looking for, whenever the usr presses tab button, the next row cell gets selected, the selected row cell's border, I would like paint in a different colour from the rest...

Comment: So why not put that as an edit to your post (and turn it into a question be prefixing it with "How to.." & suffixing it with "?")?  Is it really so difficult to form a **question?**

Comment: Do. Not. use. KeyListener. Use Keybindings instead (as you were already advised in your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551502/how-to-make-scroll-pane-static)

Comment: plus read up on and understand the renderer mechanism (what you are doing in that snippet is completely wrong - that cant work)

Answer (score 1):

There no reason for bothering with `KeyEvents` from `KeyListener`, if not generated some extra special `Events`, implements `prepareRenderer`, and there you have to test if is `isSelected()` or `hasFocus()`, I think that everything and nothing better around as @camickr's [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/),

Comment: @JeeteshNataraj no need to (in fact would be as wrong as a keylistener in your requirement) - read up about renderers (hint: it's a simple configuration task, either in a custom renderer or in table's prepareRenderer)